# Peewee. Выбор полей из двух таблиц

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, peewee

Есть классический пример: `query = Album.select().join(Artist)`, но этот запрос не выбирает поле `Artist.name`.
Как его выбрать?
Или как можно объединить две таблицы без `JOIN`?

Comment: попробуйте так `query = Album.select(Artist.name, *Album._meta.fields.values()).join(Artist)` должно выбрать все поля Album и Artist.name.

Comment: что-то ничего не получается - поле Artist.name содержит значение "None". Тогда теоретически и просто query = Album.select(Artist.name).join(Artist) должно работать, а не работает

Comment: проверяю так:for k in query: print(k.name)

Comment: вот у меня есть работающий запрос на чистом SQLite: SELECT DISTINCT "t1"."artist_id", "t2"."name" FROM "album" AS "t1" INNER JOIN "artist" AS "t2" ON ("t1"."artist_id" = "t2"."id") и нужен такой же на Peewee