# Peewee. Простой запрос на выборку

Tags: python, peewee

```
class Table(Model):
    subject_id = ForeignKeyField(Subject)
    name = CharField()
    year = SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

Выполняю запрос из документации `q = Table.[5]` или `q = Table.get_by_id(5)` и получаю значения так `q.year >>> 2018`, но `q.subject_id` возвращает значение `"<models.Table object at 0x02B82430>"`. Как получить это значение?

Comment: Попробуйте: `q.subject_id.<поле_объекта_Subject>`, например `q.subject_id.id`

Comment: да получилось, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того что поле `subject_id` ссылается на таблицу `Subject`.
Т.е создание объекта `Table` может выглядеть так:

```
subject, status = Subject.create(some_fields=...)
table = Table.create(subject_id=subject, name='Name', year=2018)
```

Также заметил что вы предположительно в каждом класса пишите:

```
class Meta:
    database = db
```

Чтобы этого избежать, можно поступить так:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

И при создании моделей делать так:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    ...
```

Comment: спасибо за ваше объяснение, вижу вы хорошо в этом разбираетесь. Может вы можете ответить на другой мой похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843558/peewee-Выбор-полей-из-двух-таблиц

Comment: @MyNick http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: спасибо большое! Разобрался наконец-то

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте: `q.subject_id.<поле_объекта_Subject>`, например `q.subject_id.id`

Т.к. при использовании `ForeignKeyField(Subject)` будет создан объект-ссылка на `Subject`, поэтому чтобы не путаться лучше так объявить поле:

```
subject = ForeignKeyField(Subject)
```

И обращаться соответственно: `q.subject.id`